# I want to to protect a config file by vim blowfish2 encryption in linux

Tags: linux, vim, centos6, password-protection

i have a problem when i protect a config file example.conf in centos 6 by Vim password protection with blowfish2 encryption the file can be read when i restart httpd i found this error : Syntax error on line 1 of example.conf
so my question there's any way to protect this example.conf by password and working without errors like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, unless a program specifically supports reading encrypted config files, a config file has to be in plaintext. You can't just go about and encrypt it without "telling" that program about it.

In your example, by encrypting that file in vim, you replaced it by seemingly random gibberish, so when you start your program, it reads a config file that doesn't match what it was expecting, so it fails.

A better option probably would be to use `chmod` to make sure only the program and trusted users can read and/or edit the file.

Btw, I think your question might be easier to answer if you edited it to clarify what service/program you are talking about and why you want to encrypt that config file.